# Selecting all electoral division within local electoral area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, select-by-location, within

I have two vector layers:

- electoral divisions (blue)(similar to counties)
- local electoral areas (green outline) (similar to states).

I'd like to select all EDs **'within'** a state using 'Select by Location' however **'within'** doesn't select the EDs which touch the borders of the LEA (see selected EDs in yellow).

I'd eventually like to export the attribute table as a lookup **detailing the EDs that sit within each LEA.**

[image: Selected ED within LEA]

Comment: The electoral divisions that share a boundary with the electoral areas are not *completely within* the electoral areas, hence not being selected. Does `intersects` work as you wish? For associating the attributes, you will probably want to look into *Join attributes by location*, rather than making a selection.

Comment: PostGIS has a `covers` operator that should do this, but it seems that select by location doesn't

Comment: You can intersect them, sort by area, delete duplicates. Join the electoral columns  back to the original divisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible path is to create a new attribute with the centroids of the smaller areas, and then select all the points that are inside the larger polygon.

Comment: Thanks! Tried this and it worked for ~99% of the EDs, the rest I could get manually.

Answer (score 4):

Use select by expression with this expression. It creates a small buffer around the electoral areas to be sure that all electoral divisions are completely within:

```
within (
    $geometry,
    overlay_nearest (
        'polygon',
        buffer ($geometry, 1)
    )[0]
)
```

- `polygon` on line 4 is the name of the electoral areas
- `1` on line 5 is the buffer's distance

Comment: won't that select the neighbouring areas (i.e. just outside the polygon) too?

Comment: Shouldn't, if the buffer is small enough that the neighboring polygons are not covered completely (thus not completely **within**). Can't test it right now.

Comment: Sorry, thought you used intersects

Answer (score 4):

I recommend installing the [Select Within](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SelectWithin/) Plugin. It has the option to select the polygons where their centroids are located inside the polygons of the other layer.

[image]

Using this option, you can avoid any duplicates that occur when using the `intersect` predicate inside the `Select by location` tool.